# What is the meaning of Parsec String () (String,String)?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I understand the `Parsec` modules' `parse` function, which takes a rule argument, an error message, and an input string:

```
parse rule text = Parsec.parse rule "(source)" text
```

However, I don't understand the meaning of `Parsec.Parsec`, or how it's different from `Parsec.ParsecT`. Why do type signatures of custom parsers use this name?

For example, in the following code snippet taken from [this blogpost](http://unbui.lt/#!/post/haskell-parsec-basics),

```
myParser :: Parsec.Parsec String () (String,String)
myParser = do
    letters <- Parsec.many1 Parsec.letter
    Parsec.spaces
    digits <- Parsec.many1 Parsec.digit
    return (letters,digits)
```

what does `Parsec.Parsec` and `()` mean in `myParser`'s type signature?

Comment: `ParsecT` and `Parsec` are defined and explained in the `Text.Parsec.Prim` module. Have a look at it on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `ParsecT` and `Parsec`

In `parsec` 3, `ParsecT` and `Parsec` are defined and explained in the [`Text.Parsec.Prim` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html):

> `data ParsecT s u m a`
>
> `ParsecT s u m a` is a parser with stream type `s`, user state type `u`, underlying monad `m` and return type `a`.

(Examples of stream types are `String`, `ByteString`, and `Text`.)

`Parsec` is simply  a version of `ParsecT` specialised to the [`Identity` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html):

> `type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Identity`

## The signature of `myParser` explained

Going back to your type signature, in

```
myParser :: Parsec.Parsec String () (String,String)
```

- the stream type is `String`;
- the user state is simply the empty tuple (also known as "unit"); in other words, `myParser` parses something but doesn't keep track of any useful state;
- the result type is a pair of `String`s.

Moreover, the type signature uses `Parsec.Parsec` (and not simply `Parsec`) because, in [the blogpost you link to](http://unbui.lt/#!/post/haskell-parsec-basics), `Text.Parsec` is imported [*qualified*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Qualified_names) as `Parsec`.

## The `Parser` type synonym

If all your parsers have stream type `String` and don't keep track of any state, you probably want to abstract some of that `parsec` complexity away. In that case, you should use the `Parser` type synonym, which the `Text.Parsec.String` module defines as

```
type Parser = Parsec String ()
```

For instance, with the following import

```
import Text.Parsec.String ( Parser )
```

you can simplify `myParser`'s type signature to

```
myParser :: Parser (String, String)
```